# How to retrieve results from Struct in array

Tags: swift, struct, enums

I have an enum and Struct that looks like the following.

```
enum Position: String {
    case lw = "Left Wing"
    case rw = "Right Wing"
    case c  = "Centre"
    case d  = "Defense"
    case g  = "Goalie"
}

struct PlayerInformation {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let position: Position
    let number: Int

}

struct ShiftDetails {
    let player: PlayerInformation
    var timeOnIce: Int
    var dateOnIce: Date
}
```

I build the `playerInformationArray` with the following:

```
var playerInformationArray = [PlayerInformation]()

let sidneyCrosby      = PlayerInformation.init(firstName: "Sidney", lastName: "Crosby", position: Position.c, number: 87)
let alexOvechkin      = PlayerInformation.init(firstName: "Alex", lastName: "Ovechkin", position: Position.lw, number: 8)
let patrickKane       = PlayerInformation.init(firstName: "Patrick", lastName: "Kane", position: Position.rw, number: 88)

playerInformationArray.append(sidneyCrosby)
playerInformationArray.append(alexOvechkin)
playerInformationArray.append(patrickKane)
```

I store information about a players "shift" in the following array:

```
var shiftDetails = [ShiftDetails]()
```

I retrieve the information about the "selected" player from a collection view with the following:

```
let selectedPlayer = playerInformationArray[indexPath.row]
```

I then update the `shiftDetails` array with the following:

```
shiftDetails.append( ShiftDetails.init(player: selectedPlayer, timeOnIce: timerCounter, dateOnIce: Date()) )
```

Everything works as excepted, but I'm having a hard time understanding, how to retrieve data from the arrays.  For example:

How would I retrieve the `count` of `shiftDetails` per player?

How would I retrieve the `sum` of `timeOnIce` per player?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check if certain player is equal to another player you need to make it conform to Equatable protocol implementing the double equal operator `==`. You can also make your struct conform to `CustomStringConvertible and provide a custom description to it:

```
struct Player: Equatable, CustomStringConvertible {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let position: Position
    let number: Int
    static func ==(lhs: Player, rhs: Player) -> Bool {
        return lhs.firstName == rhs.firstName && lhs.lastName == rhs.lastName
    }
    var description: String {
        return "Player: " + firstName + " " + lastName
    }
}
```

---

Also in Swift you should always prefer long names (camelCase) for better readability and try to avoid redundant information when naming your properties and you shouldn't add the type to your object names:

```
enum Position: String {
    case leftWing = "Left Wing"
    case rightWing = "Right Wing"
    case center  = "Center"
    case defense  = "Defense"
    case golie  = "Goalie"
}

struct Shift {
    let player: Player
    var timeOnIce: Int
    var dateOnIce: Date
}
```

---

```
var players: [Player] = []

let sidneyCrosby = Player(firstName: "Sidney", lastName: "Crosby", position: .center, number: 87)
let alexOvechkin = Player(firstName: "Alex", lastName: "Ovechkin", position: .leftWing, number: 8)
let patrickKane = Player(firstName: "Patrick", lastName: "Kane", position: .rightWing, number: 88)

players += [sidneyCrosby, alexOvechkin, patrickKane]

var shifts: [Shift] = []
var index = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
var selectedPlayer = players[index.row]
let shift1 = Shift(player: selectedPlayer, timeOnIce: 3, dateOnIce: Date())
shifts.append(shift1)
let shift2 = Shift(player: selectedPlayer, timeOnIce: 5, dateOnIce: Date())
shifts.append(shift2)
```

---

To sum timeOnIce property per player and its count, you could extend Array constraining the elements to Shift type:

```
extension Array  where Element == Shift {
    func timeOnIceAndCount(for player: Player) -> (timeOnIce: Int, count: Int) {
        return reduce((0,0)) {
            $1.player == player ? ($0.0 + $1.timeOnIce, $0.1 + 1) : $0
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
let (timeOnIce, count) = shifts.timeOnIceAndCount(for: selectedPlayer)
print(selectedPlayer)
print("TimeOnIce:",timeOnIce)
print("Count: ", count)
```

This will print

> Player: Sidney Crosby
>
> TimeOnIce: 8
>
> Count:  2

Comment: Thanks for this, you're a rock star!!. However, I believe you have a typo in `(for player: Player)` should be `(for selectedPlayer: Player)` however I get the following error: `Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types '(_, _)' and '_'`

Comment: @PaulS The method signature naming was correct. It actually should be  `$1.player == player` instead of `$1.player == selectedPlayer` inside the closure.

Comment: thanks for the clarification.  it's still returning `Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types '(_, _)' and '_'`

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ej325owlyc5qd7h/AADE1_AXPtL2uy_jnQ8GHrHaa?dl=1

Comment: Thanks for the playground.  you're correct, works fine in Playground, but as an extension in my UIViewController, I get the message indicated above.

Comment: @PaulS. If you have a sample project I can check whats wrong with it otherwise I would be just guessing

Comment: Try this.  Open new project in xcode.  Past the extension at the end of your viewcontroller, paste the Struct.  Build, and you'll see the error.

Comment: @PaulS. Just compress the parent folder and send me the link

Answer (score 0):

This may not end up being the cleanest way of doing this since all your shiftDetails are held in a single, shared array, but in order to accomplish this with your current setup you could use the built-in `filter` function to get information about a given player.  This could look something like this:

```
let selectedPlayer = playerInformationArray[indexPath.row]
let filteredDetails = shiftDetails.filter({ $0.player == selectedPlayer })
let shiftCount = filteredDetails.count
let timeOnIce = filteredDetails.reduce(0, { $0 + $1.timeOnIce })
```

Another option would be to maintain a shiftDetails array for each player, at which point you don't need to do any filtering.  Or, another option would be to have the shiftDetails be a dictionary where the key is the player and the value is an array of shiftDetails.

It is also worth noting that my example of the `filter` function assumes your Player struct conforms to the Equatable protocol - in other words, that you can legally say `playerOne == playerTwo`.  If you don't do this you would have to match on some other unique field such as name or playerId or something like that.